# How to do identify non-Ubuntu software

Tags: uninstall

How can one identify, and remove, software which is installed on Ubuntu (14.04) which is non-Ubuntu software?

I understand I need to do this so that my upgrade to 16.04 isn't blocked.

From various posts I have tried these to no avail.

This returns nothing

> grep ppa /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

This

```
> ls  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

returns

```
ros-latest.list  ros-latest.list.distUpgrade  ros-latest.list.save
```

Is this what I need to remove?

I have tried the following, but am clearly missing some knowledge.

```
> sudo ppa-purge ros-latest
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ros-latest ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ros-latest ppa

> sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ros-latest
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ros-latest'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?